# gcc can't link to pthread?

Tags: c, libraries, gcc, xubuntu

I have recently installed XUbuntu 11.10 64bit, but I am having problem compiling the most simple pthread example.

Here is the code `pthread_simple.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
main()  {
  pthread_t f2_thread, f1_thread; 
  void *f2(), *f1();
  int i1,i2;
  i1 = 1;
  i2 = 2;
  pthread_create(&f1_thread,NULL,f1,&i1);
  pthread_create(&f2_thread,NULL,f2,&i2);
  pthread_join(f1_thread,NULL);
  pthread_join(f2_thread,NULL);
}
void *f1(int *x){
  int i;
  i = *x;
  sleep(1);
  printf("f1: %d",i);
  pthread_exit(0); 
}
void *f2(int *x){
  int i;
  i = *x;
  sleep(1);
  printf("f2: %d",i);
  pthread_exit(0); 
}
```

And here is the compile command

```
gcc -lpthread pthread_simple.c
```

The results:

```
lptang@tlp-linux:~/test/test-pthread$ gcc -lpthread pthread_simple.c 
/tmp/ccmV0LdM.o: In function `main':
pthread_simple.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread_simple.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread_simple.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pthread_simple.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what's causing the problem?

Comment: Is it stackexchange's fault that you have empty includes in the first two lines? There should be an `#include <pthread.h>`

Comment: Yes, I used the pre environment. It should now display correctly.

Comment: [Tried `gcc -pthread...`?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665110/993018)

Comment: BTW, please compile with `-Wall`, you're missing headers. (And sr_ is correct.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the latest versions of `gcc` compiler require that libraries follow the object or source files.

So to compile this it should be:

```
gcc pthread_sample.c -lpthread
```

Normally though pthread code is compiled this way:

```
gcc -pthread pthread_sample.c
```

Comment: @Karlson Can you please explain why just including the `pthread.h` file is not enough for gcc to resolve the references?

Comment: @iamcreasy Because declaration is not the same as definition.  The program needs to know where the code executing a particular function is.

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell us what's the difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread`. Some tutorial add `-l` some don't, why?

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -o exectable_namme pthread_sample.c -lpthread
```

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/244330/edit) to explain why this is different from the already accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

compile code using following command

```
gcc filename.c -lpthread -lrt
```

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful if you could edit your answer to explain why it works, and to highlight why you think it adds something the already accepted answer doesn't cover.